# How to obtain generating function and an analytic solution

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have the following recurrence relation, and I need to obtain generating function and an analytic solution. How to go about with it?

$$
f(N,M) = 0, N < M\\
f(N+1,M+1) = 2f(N,M) + (N-1)f(N,M+1), N > 0, M > 0\\
f(1,1) = 1\\
f(N,1) = 0, N > 1\\
$$

PS: this is not homework. A problem I encountered during a discussion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Denote $F(x,y)=\sum_{N,M\ge 1}f_{N,M}x^Ny^M$. If I'm not mistaken in calculations, then 
$$
F=1+2xyF-xF+ x^2\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}.
$$

Comment: +1. Thank you, Boris. Any further simplification please?

Comment: No proposals. I think one should decide this differential equation for fixed $y$.